# Convert NSDate to NString issue

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

Hi I m pick the date from **UIDatePicker** and convert it in NSstring.. All the date working fine. Hi have set maximum date as **2001-12-31**. When i choose this date the string return as
**"2002-12-31"**

```
dOBPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 360, 55)];
dOBPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;


NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd";
dOBPicker.maximumDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2001-12-31"];
```

Conversion here

```
NSDateFormatter *dateOfBirthFormat =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateOfBirthFormat.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd";

[dateOfBirthFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSString *dob = [dateOfBirthFormat stringFromDate:dOBPicker.date];

NSLog(@"The dob is %@", dob);
```

Output as : **2002-12-31**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "yyyy" not "YYYY".

"Y": Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars). Normally the length specifies the padding, but for two letters it also specifies the maximum length. This year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. May not always be the same value as calendar year.

```
Y   year of "Week of Year":  
    Y -> 1997
```

"y": Year. Normally the length specifies the padding, but for two letters it also specifies the maximum length.

```
y   year:   
    yy -> 96  
    y or yyyy -> 1996
```

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)
Also: [CLDR Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

Comment: Thanks for your response i ll check

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your formatting to this :

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd"
```